# windows library for _chkstk_ms() function

Tags: c, visual-c++, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I have one windows project built in VS 2015 in windows7. Now I have to use one third party library (implemented in C) built in Mingw - 64 bit (for windows). When I try to link this library I am getting one compilation error :--

Unresolved external symbol __chkstk_ms.

Now I have resolved this issue by linking 2 more libs - libgcc.a and libssp.a.

But after, that when I run my application, I have started getting memory exception in some routines which was working fine previously.

I have doubt I should not solve this compilation error by using these 2 libraries (as these are not windows). Instead of it, there should be some windows / VC run time library which should be providing implementation of this routine.

Can someone please suggest right way to resolve this linking error.

Comment: `__chkstk_ms` seems to be a known problem, but I don't see a simple solution. You need it to activate MS check stack function and commit stack pages, but I suspect that linking in the gcc lib's there will be a mallocing related problem. What I would suggest is: if you have static libraries containing `__chkstk_ms` you can try to extract it (and eventually related routines) and link their obj's. Very experimental, it requires time and resources. Unfortunately I can't try myself.

Comment: @Frankie_C Thanks for your answer. Somehow I have gotten the access of code of third party. But I am not sure how can I find out that which piece of code is causing use of __chkstk_ms routine. Is there any to get this information ?

Comment: Any allocation of a large automatic variable, as an array, triggers the stack check for stack overflow and pages commit.